# Unable to locate puppetdb using puppet

Tags: installation, puppet

I am in process of installing puppet and I have already installed puppetserver on Ubuntu16.10 and puppet-agent also on Ubuntu16.10 on virtual machine. Next step, following [this official guide](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/4.3/install_from_packages.html) the next step after puppet-agent installation is to install PuppetDB. When I run `puppet agent --test` it successfully completes. Puppet Collection package is enabled and when I run `sudo /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet resource package puppetdb ensure=latest` here is an error: 
[image]
`puppet agent version` returns `4.9.2`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you failed to subscribe to the apt repo containing the puppetdb package in Step 2.

Comment: @MattSchuchard you're right. Ubuntu16.10 is yakkety, but following Puppet Collection 1 didn't work on this distribution unlike Xenial. So, I suppose that's yakkety PC1 problem. :)
I was stuck with the same problem when trying to install puppetserver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enabling the **Puppet Collection** package repository for **Xenial** solves the problem with, particularly puppetserver and puppetdb packages on Ubuntu16.10.

Comment: It would be nice to explain **how** to enable to _"Puppet Collection package repository for Xenial"_